# Keeping services awake without draining battery

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have an application that needs to continuously listen for incoming requests over wifi. A service that runs in the background does this job. However, this service falls asleep after a while when the screen turns off.

The solution from what I have searched is to use AlarmManager to keep it awake. But it is said that this will drain the battery of the device.
So, is there another way to do this?

For eg, what do apps like Whatsapp and Skype do? They don't seem to kill too much battery but they have continuously running services right?

Also, in case AlarmManager is the only way, it would be really kind if someone could share a tutorial or example for it.

Answer (score 2):

> The solution from what I have searched is to use AlarmManager to keep it awake

That will not help. Once the device falls asleep, your socket connection will be terminated. You would need to use a partial `WakeLock` plus a `WifiLock` to keep the device powered on continuously.

> But it is said that this will drain the battery of the device.

The `WakeLock` and `WifiLock` will definitely drain the battery.

> So, is there another way to do this?

Not if you need to use WiFi.

> For eg, what do apps like Whatsapp and Skype do?

They do not use WiFi when the device wants to go to sleep. Once the WiFi radio powers down, they use mobile data, so no `WifiLock` is needed. For mobile data, incoming packets will wake up the device, so you only need a `WakeLock` while you are actually doing work, rather than constantly.

The best answer is to switch to use C2DM, though.

Comment: "Once the WiFi radio powers down, they use mobile data" -- But why do I still can receive WhatsApp message even if the phone is asleep and mobile data is turned off (WiFi was on)? Thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare what do you add on here?

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder: My guess would be that they use `AlarmManager` on a polling basis in situations like this (e.g., check for new messages every 15 minutes via WiFi), but that is just a guess. Beyond that, talk to Whatsapp.

Answer (score 2):

Actually its not your service which falls to sleep, its your WiFi unit on the device. Manufacturers like HTC (or perhaps all Android devices) have implemented this kind of behavior on their devices in which the WiFi unit goes standby after certain time period of screen-off. This helps the devices to save battery when its not being used.